# Using an extension of UrlHelper without reference in chtml page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, urlhelper

I have an extension of UrlHelper, I'll use on every page chtml. Do I have any way to refer to this extension without having to do it by using?

**UrlExtender.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MySite.Web.MVC.Extender
{
    public static class UrlExtender
    {
        public static string ContentLastWrite(this UrlHelper helper, string contentPath)
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime lastWriteTime = (new FileInfo(helper.RequestContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(contentPath))).LastWriteTime;
                contentPath = string.Format("{0}?v={1:yyyyMMddHHmmss}", contentPath, lastWriteTime);

                return helper.Content(contentPath);
            }
            catch
            {
                return helper.Content(contentPath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**page.chtml**

```
@using MySite.Web.MVC.Extender


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.ContentLastWrite("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
...
```

I want to avoid calling "MySite.Web.MVC.Extender" on every page "chtml"

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `<add namespace="MySite.Web.MVC.Extender" />` to `<system.web.webPages.razor>/<pages>/<namespaces>` in `Views/Web.config`.